# RDLC show sum of rows c#

Tags: c#, parameters, report, rdlc

I read many articles and find code/ expression to show sum of rows in RDLC report but I didn't get the idea because I am new and needs to know step by step.

I make report and add expression like name, date by going to Report Data.

In my report there is 2 more columns i.e. Invoice and Settlement.  want to show sum of all invoice and settlement at the end of my report.

I try to add parameter but didn't get any thing.

Can anyone please help me to achieve this goal step by step. It really great favor. Advance thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps -

- Right click on field where you want to show sum
- Select expression
- Select sum under aggregate
- for example: =Sum(Fields!Invoice.Value)

(Example was for invoice and do same for settlement value)